# Why Is One Of The Eclipse Workspace Projects Marked Differently?

Tags: eclipse

Please have a look at the Eclipse Project Explorer screen shot below. Note that the dmeScripts project has:

1. A `>` symbol next to its icon
2. The text "[dmeScripts master]" after its name
3. A `>` symbol next to its src folder's icon
4. A `>` symbol next to its pom file's icon

None of the other projects have these "decorators(?)". Would someone please tell me the significance of these decorators?

Note: The workspace shown in the screen shot was newly created in a folder containing three project folders that had been copied from another, existing workspace. The 3 projects were then imported (import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects) into the new workspace. The decorators are not present in the original workspace from which the projects were copied.

[image: Eclipse Project Explorer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is being managed by a Source Control System, probably GIT in this instance.

The information in [] is the repository and branch.

The '>' means changes are pending.

The 'Team' section of the 'Preferences' has more information on the decorations.

Right clicking on the project should show a 'Team' menu which is used to manage the source control system.